# Can I use Inno Setup as a service and a normal process?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to create an Installer and an Updater.
I want the updater to have the ability to run as a service and a normal process(Depending on if I run the installer as an admin or not).
I created my app that has the ability to run as a service and a normal process, so i could assume that this is also achievable in inno setup.
Could I create an installer that would behave like a service and a normal process?

Comment: What does it mean *"want the updater to have the ability to run as a service"*? Why do you need to run it as a service? What would the service do?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to have an Inno installer run **as** a service, because it is not a service application.

It *is* possible to have a service process launch an Inno installer from a non-user context to eg. auto-upgrade itself.  However doing this requires very careful attention.

For example, you must:

- Launch the installer with `/VERYSILENT /SUPPRESSMSGBOXES /NORESTART` to hide all standard UI.
- Use `AppMutex` (with a corresponding mutex in the `Global` namespace) to ensure that the installer waits until the service has terminated itself after launching the installer.
- Ensure the launching process is already elevated to admin (note that this is a security risk, as it means that the service runs with admin permissions during normal operation).
- Ensure that before launching the installer, the service makes **very damn sure** that it is running a legit upgrade package and not some malware.  Digital signature verification is strongly encouraged.
- Ensure that the script does not use `MsgBox` or otherwise display UI.  (Use `SuppressibleMsgBox` if needed for the interactive install.)

TLDR: while you can, you shouldn't.  It's hard to get right and it's very easy to open security holes.  Just let users download and run installers themselves.

Comment: You probably want to use [`CheckForMutexes` function](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_checkformutexes) (in a loop) to wait for the mutex instead of [`AppMutex` directive](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_appmutex). The `AppMutex` will abort the installer (in silent mode). If the service does not exit before the installer gets to the mutex check (what you can hardly guarantee), the installer won't run.

Comment: My goal is to create a silent auto updater. Is it possible for the application, which runs as a service, to call the updater itself when no user is logged in? I know that services can run when no user is logged in, so I assumed that I also need an upater to be a service so it could update without any user logged in.

Comment: I also need to run the updater  from an elevated source so the UAC won't show up. If I call the updater from a service will the UAC pop up or not?

Comment: If you run the installer from an already-elevated process then UAC won't show up, however `runasoriginaluser` and friends will then also run elevated.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl When running in silent mode, Inno automatically loops for a little while checking the mutex.  It will only abort if the application takes a really long time to exit, so you should make sure that you shut down as much as possible before calling the installer and then exit immediately afterwards.

Comment: I do not think that Inno Setup waits for the mutex. See a call `CheckForMutexes` in `InitializeSetup`.

Comment: Hmm.  You're right, it doesn't seem to do that after all.  I'm sure it did at some point though, but maybe that was an unofficial branch.